# FB.login() returns null on first call

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have this js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.login-link').click(function () {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(resp) {
          console.log('Good to see you, ' + resp.name + '.');
        });
      } else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
      }
    }, {scope: 'email'});

  });
});
```

which is bound to `<div class="login-link">FB modal login</div>`

The problem is when I click the button the FB.login and authorize the app the response.authResponse is null and response.status is not_authorized. If I click it again or refresh the page it shows user has authorized the app but obviously I need it the first time. The code is taken from [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) with minor modifications.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wanted to show a workaround on this issue if someone else is also struggling on it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.login-link').click(function () {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
      }, true);
    }, {scope: 'email'});
  });
});
```

I leave my question open because it doesn't really answers the question why FB.login is not working but at least provides a temporary solution.